# Running Magento behind NAT?

Tags: magento, webserver, nat, virtual-hosts

I'm trying to run Magento behind NAT, where the nat port is not 80 ?
F.e.  www.mysite.com:4444  =to internal=>  192.168.100.10:80

The problem is that it seems that the front page loads dynamically the rest of the site... This is how the beginning of the loaded front page looks like :

> var require = {
>           "baseUrl": "...://www.mysite.com/static/version1498705433/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US"
>       };

So nothing beside the front page loads, everything else timeouts.

if you look closely you wont see the NAT port :4444 in the baseURL i.e. the "loader" should look like :

> var require = {
>           "baseUrl": "....://www.mysite.com:4444/static/version1498705433/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US"
>       };

Is there a  way to solve this ? i.e. run Magento behind NAT, where the NAT port is not 80 ?

Comment: You need to add :4444 to the base url, this was already asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201187/running-magento-on-other-port-than-default-80). Alternatively you can use some kind of reverse proxy service, [this](https://openport.io/) looks like something that can do what you need(never used it myself and don't know anything about it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento set the Stores / Configuration / Web /Base URL to : ....://www.mysite.com:4444