# What to use as base url in magento2 when using docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, magento, magento2

I have simple docker orchestration to serve Magento files
here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
    php:
        build: docker/php
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html

    db:
        image: mariadb:10.4
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: magento
        volumes:
            - ./docker/mysql/databases:/var/lib/mysql

    nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
            - 8009:80
        links:
            - php:phpfpm
        volumes:
            - ./docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./docker/nginx/magento.conf:/etc/nginx/magento.conf
            - .:/var/www/html

    elasticsearch:
        image: bitnami/elasticsearch:7
        ports:
            - 9200:9200
        volumes:
            - ./docker/elasticsearch/data:/bitnami/elasticsearch/data
```

as you see, I want to serve the store on my host machine port 8009.

My question is, what should I set base-url when using setup:install command and installing my Magento store?
If I set it to something like localhost or 127.0.0.1, when accessing localhost:8009 it redirects me to 127.0.0.1 which is obviously the wrong location

Comment: Did you try just adding port at the end base_url=localhost:8009?
Here is a question about this subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201187/running-magento-on-other-port-than-default-80

Comment: yes @Shmuel, that way works. but I need it to work regardless of out-of-container address and port. multiple people use the container on different ports, and I production we may wanna use a reverse proxy which I don't think would work this way

Comment: `when accessing localhost:8009 it redirects me to 127.0.0.1` - you can access to 127.0.0.1:8009, this should be correct.

Comment: @PetroChaikivskyi yes, but I need it to work on port 80 inside the container and multiple ports on the host machine

Comment: @FatemehMajd are you about Nginx container? It works on 80 port inside container and accessible on 8009 on your host. Can you tell me in more detail about your problem?

Comment: @PetroChaikivskyi. Yes, I understand. My problem is I want Magento to work on multiple ports, say localhost:8009,8010,8020, etc without changing the base-url variable

Comment: Base URL should be - `http://localhost` (`https://localhost` for SSL) when you want to access to Magento by `localhost:8009`, `localhost:8010`, `localhost:8020`, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

When you use to customer port in docker you want to use a base URL is URL: port.

example =>

> base_url=https://localhost:8009/